# What do "$i$" and "$j$ " subscript mean in statistics?

Tags: notation

I'm just curious about what the meaning of $i$ and $j$ subscript in statistic formula. I think $i$ means individual and $j$ means higher level unit in a multilevel frame work. How did statisticians come up with these two letters? What are they short for?

Comment: There's no generally accepted meaning. It depends on the context and the paper. For instance, in one econometrics course, professor used i for column vectors and j for row vectors.

Comment: That was an unkind professor.

Answer (score 7):

The $i$ and $j$ are mathematical, rather than statistical, convention.  The $i$ is because it is the first letter in the word **i**ndex, and then $j$ comes after $i$.  They have the benefit of being small, clear, and unobtrusive ($x_{ij}$ looks pretty good).

This is usually seen in the context of matrix entries, where $i$ indexes the rows, and $j$ indexes the columns.  The matrix convention is followed far and wide in general branches of mathematics and science using linear algebraic machinery.

This is what I was told in my first linear algebra course in school, I know of no definitive reference.

Comment: Hmmm, re: "... clear...", I've been in a number of classrooms where the $i$ and $j$ were essentially indistinguishable (including in my own handwriting...).

Comment: @gung The professor who taught ANOVA to us had handwriting that made i,j and . indistinguishable.  That was not conducive to learning.

Comment: That's a fair point.  You gotta emphasize that curve in the $j$!

It looks good printed though.

Comment: Mathematical convention has changed over the centuries. The use of $i$ and $j$ for indexes is by no means universal.  One convention that *is* documented was the determination that all variables beginning with the letters "i" through "n" would automatically be considered INtegers in FORTRAN (and therefore were frequently used as INdexes).  Given that the designers of FORTRAN spoke English, this makes sense. As an explanation, it makes less sense in the mathematical community of the early 20th century where the leaders tended to write in French (les Entiers) or German (die Zahlen).

Comment: I just checked some old (stats-related) papers; K.Pearson [here](http://stat.smmu.edu.cn/history/pearson1901.pdf) (1901) uses $u$ and $v$. Fisher [here](https://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/15186/1/42.pdf) (1925) uses $k$ and $j$, whereas [here](https://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/15187/1/43.pdf) (also 1925) he uses $i$ and $j$. To my recollection I've seen him use $i$ and $j$ in other papers from the 20's. Not much of a sample (only tried 3), and obtained haphazardly, but I thought it was interesting. One $i,j$ use pre-FORTRAN, anyway.

Comment: @Glen Yes, Fortran was building on what had become conventional in some communities.  But in the mid-19th century, for instance, many people did not even use subscripts.  Papers would refer to "$A, B, \ldots, Z$" for instance, rather than "$A_i, i=1, 2, \ldots$". Although Fisher is only a sample of one or two, it was surely his work on ANOVA and his stats text that would have established conventional notation for a very long time.

Comment: @whuber I recall the $A, B, C$ thing from reading Gauss's papers on differential geometry in school.

Comment: That's precisely what I had in mind.  Gauss's original notation $E,F,G$ for [the metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstFundamentalForm.html) and $L,M,N$ for the [second fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form) persists today.